# App to lock phone with PIN

Tags: lock-screens, samsung

Device: Samsung Galaxy SGH-S730G
Android: 4.0.4

When my phone is on me, I don't want to use a PIN, password, or pattern on my lock screen. I just want to swipe to unlock quickly. However, if I leave my phone somewhere, I'd like to lock it with a PIN or password. Is there an app that will let me lock my phone with some kind of security, even though my normal settings just use swipe-to-unlock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App/shortcut to quickly change screen lock type?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/app-shortcut-to-quickly-change-screen-lock-type)

Comment: Actually, yes, it's the same question, but from 3 years ago, and all the answers are for Android 2.* Looking for some more up to date information.

Comment: ah, I didn't notice that, sorry. To be honest though, Tasker is probably your best bet as it can be customised to how you want it. There may be other newer apps though.

Comment: I'd vote to keep this question open, if only for more updated answers to the one recommended duplicate.

Comment: I second the "keep open", for another reason: it's not really a duplicate, rather a "close relative". Here the question is not about a location, but about whether the device is in reach of its owner. So possible solutions could include things like "bluetooth proximity" (requiring a second device "attached" to the owner), or even an "NFC ring" on your finger to unlock the device.